# How to detect and avoid infinite loop in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

This question is not about a bug in my PHP code (for the moment I don't have any PHP script, I am still thinking about the algorithm). Here is the problem:

I'm currently working on a mechanical piece manager which would be able to build a mechanical piece based on internal part (for example, I got a piece which is a Bike, and for that piece, I need 2 wheels, 1 handlebar, and for a wheel I need a tire etc).

Each internal part is also a mechanical piece in my database and is linked with a unique ID (and has a folder which contains many PDF, many 3D files, etc).

I got a GUI (in HTML) representing my database and each piece has a "Build" button to gather all files required to build internal piece.

For example:

My bike has the ID n°1, a wheel has the ID n°2 and the handlebar has the ID n°3.

The algorithm is pretty simple but vulnerable with infinite loop.

How could I do to avoid this following case: What if my bike (id 1) need a wheel (id 2), and my wheel need a bike...which needs a wheel which need a bike......?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Why would your wheel need a bike? A wheel is a part can could be used for many more products, bikes, cars, skates, skateboards. A wheel can exist for itself, but a bike doesn't.

Comment: Just found somewhat related: [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94669/adjacency-list-with-array-data), consider parent as bike and wheel as a child.

Comment: I assume that in the future, my database will have thousands of article and a mistake could be easily done. If it was up to me, I wouldn't care but... I work for people who care... ahah

Comment: You need to keep track and check when you instantiate a new Part, that it's not present in it's parent objects - that's a simple way to avoid infinite loops in your case. Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: Is this question related to algorithm tag?

Comment: This looks like has-and-belongs-to-many relationship between your elements

Comment: You could create a graph of your relationships and use a standard graph algorithm to detect any loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the execution of your build function, you would just keep track of all components that you have already produced a result for -- in a hash --, and if you encounter one of those again, you just ignore it.

Here is some boilerplate code you could use for inspiration:

```
// Sample "database":
$components = array(
    1 => array (
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "bike",
        "needs" => array (
            array ("id" => 2, "count" => 2), // 2 wheels
            array ("id" => 3, "count" => 1), // 1 handlebar
        ),
        "folder" => "/my/folders/bike"
    ),
    2 => array(
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "weel",
        "needs" => array(
            array("id" => 4, "count" => 1), // 1 tire
            array("id" => 1, "count" => 1)  // 1 wheel?? - erroneous information!
        ),
        "folder" => "/my/folders/wheel"
    ),
    3 => array(
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "handlebar",
        "needs" => array (),
        "folder" => "/my/folders/handlebar"
    ),
    4 => array(
        "id" => 4,
        "name" => "tire",
        "needs" => array(),
        "folder" => "/my/folders/tire"
    )
);  

// Build function: returns a list of folders related
// to all the parts of the given component.
function build($componentId, $components, $hash = array()) {
    // Protection against infinite recursion:
    if (isset($hash[$componentId])) return []; 
    $elem = $components[$componentId];
    // set hash, keyed by component ID.
    $hash[$componentId] = 1;
    // Add folder for this component
    $folders[] = $elem['folder'];
    // Collect folders of dependent components recursively
    foreach($elem['needs'] as $child ) {
        // ... pass the hash as third argument
        $folders = array_merge($folders, build($child["id"], $components, $hash));
    }
    return $folders;
}

// Example call: build component with ID 1, returning a list of folders:
print_r (build(1, $components));
```

The output of the above code would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /my/folders/bike
    [1] => /my/folders/wheel
    [2] => /my/folders/tire
    [3] => /my/folders/handlebar
)
```

So when the bike was encountered a second time, it was just ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used your solution but I made some update, I don't do  $hash[$componentId] = 1; but $hash[] = $componentId, and then instead of isset() I use in_array() ! Thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Comment: You're welcome. Your variation will also work, but is slower, as `in_array` may potentially have to search the whole array, while `isset` runs in constant time. However, on a dataset with only like 100 components, the difference will not be that significant. It would become noticeable if you would have 1000 or more components.

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate the child-parent relations.

A bike can contain a wheel as a child item and a wheel may have a bike as its parent item. Also one screw and tire can be child items of the wheel.

Navigation should have one direction, either from parent items to child items or the opposite.

Comment: OP wants to be able to create a bike by clicking any of the parts of a bike though. This means  that in this case navigation does have more than one direction.